# Windows batch file to find files in a folder for error checking

Tags: batch-file

This part of my script is supposed to go through directories looking for *.wim files and if it finds them on the "images" folder, proceed. However, it is going straight to the "else" part of the code :/

```
ECHO. Checking for WIMs
ECHO ............................................
ECHO. 

for /F "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /B /S "%w%:\data\images"') do (
    if exist "%%~ff\*.wim" ( 
    ECHO found me some wims! let's continue.     
    GOTO actionmenu
    ) else (
         ECHO This script requires a wim repository folder to proceed. make sure you have
         ECHO properly populated the "\Images" folder before re-running this script
    goto end
    )
)
```

Comment: [DOS and windows cmd are not the same](https://superuser.com/q/451432/241386). There's no such thing like `for /f` inDOS

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: WinPE 5 command console

Comment: Are you really looking for the equivalent of, `"%w%:\*\data\images\*.wim"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't even need a `for` loop. `Dir` gives an `%errorlevel%` of `1`, if it doesn't find something:

```
dir /B /S "%w%:\data\images\*.wim" >nul && (
  echo found at least one wim file.
) || (
  echo no wim files found.
)
```

`&&` works as "if previous command was successful (`dir` found at least one file), then"
`||` is the opposite: " if previous command failed (`dir` didn't find a matching file) then"

Comment: thank you.. this is exactly what i needed. because of my lack of experience in programing and batch in general, I just don't have the imagination to look for other solutions to my problem. I tried to piece things together from people with similar projects.

Comment: `for` is one of the most powerful commands in `cmd`, but there is no law to use it under all circumstances `;)`

Answer (score 0):

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /B /S /AD "%w%:\data\images"') do (
  if exist "%%f\*.wim" ( 
    ECHO found me some wims! let's continue.     
    GOTO actionmenu
  ) else (
    ECHO This script requires a wim repository folder to proceed. make sure you have
    ECHO properly populated the "\Images" folder before re-running this script
    goto end
  )
)
```

Comment: It worked for me. Can you paste the results? I guess I don't inreally understand what you want. Is it that you want to list all the folders under %w%:\data\images that contain *.wim files?

Comment: I apologize for not being so clear. this part of the script is to make sure that the folder "Images" exists, and that there are *.wim files IN it. when i run your modified code, i do not get any echo output and it goes straight into action menu on both scenarios.. with , and without wim files in the specified directory.

Comment: I modified this to be what I think you intended and it works for me. You may want to put "@echo off" at the top so the commands don't dump to the display.

Comment: The second line in this example has a typo, it should have two percents, **`%%f`**.

Comment: I would but can't see what the actual objective is. [Stephan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48072838/2245849) is more appropriate to simply check for file existence. Using a "for /f" is for more complicated so I assume the OP needs more than just a test for existence. So I just made it so his original script would work.

Comment: thank you for your help.. alas, your snippet did not run as i intended it, but you did the best you could with what i gave you :/ .. kudos for taking the time to answer.